# Filter for a float in pandas results in nothing when I know the value exits

Tags: pandas, filter

Here's a link to the practice file I'm using
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnMRr0Q8-EGOg7kRKRCLHCIt1lT0qQ?e=1rOoWF

I am calculating a profit margin using the following code:

The table has several columns but the most important columns for my analysis look like this:

| PROCODE | AV_COST | CURSELLPRI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8030106009 | .225 | .75 |
| 1721612503 | .327 | 1.09 |

```
df = pd.read_excel('processed inventory.xlsx')

df.insert(6,'Profit',0.0)

df.loc[df['CURSELLPRI'] == 0, 'Profit'] = 0

df.loc[df['CURSELLPRI'] != 0, 'Profit'] = (df['CURSELLPRI'] - df['AV_COST']) / df['CURSELLPRI']
```

My output looks like this:

| PROCODE | AV_COST | CURSELLPRI | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8030106009 | .225 | .75 | 0.700000 |
| 1721612503 | .327 | 1.09 | 0.700000 |

When I filter for Profit = .7 or 0.7 or 0.700000 nothing returns.

I've tried several other values and nothing ever returns when I do

df[df['Profit'] == 0.XX]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) for filter by floats, because problem of precision of floats:

```
df[np.isclose(df['Profit'], 0.7)]
```

For test real values in column try convert to list:

```
print (df['Profit'].tolist())
```

Comment: should using isclose something I should just always use for floats? Sometimes I can filter floats and have no issues. Is there an explanation online somewhere for why this happens and how it can be resolved in your dataframe without using numpy?

Comment: @David54321 - It depends. If want test equal with test, need `np.isclose`. But if need less or more, then no `np.isclose` necessary. If dont need `np.isclose` is possible some tricks like `df[df['Profit'].mul(10).astype(int) ==7]]` for multiple by 10 and convert to integers and compare by integers, but in my opinion better is use `np.isclose`